# java rotating bufferedimages fast

Tags: java, image, optimization, rotation, bufferedimage

I develop a game and rotating images currently takes most of the time in the calculation process of a frame. For optimization I'm searching for the fastest way to rotate a buffered-image. I already tried two methods shown down there.

slowest method:

```
public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage imgOld, int deg){                                               //Parameter for this method are the picture to rotate and the rotation in degrees

     AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(deg), (int)(imgOld.getWidth()/2), (int)(imgOld.getHeight()/2));       //initialize and configure transformation
     BufferedImage imgNew = new BufferedImage(imgOld.getWidth(), imgOld.getHeight(), imgOld.getType());                                          //create new bufferedimage with the properties of the image to rotate
     Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) imgNew.getGraphics();                                                                                           //create Graphics
     g.setTransform(at);                                                                                                                         //apply transformation
     g.drawImage(imgOld, 0, 0, null);                                                                                                            //draw rotated image                       
     g.dispose();
     imgOld.flush();
     return imgNew;
}
```

little bit faster method :

```
 public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage imgOld, int deg){                                                 //parameter same as method above                                                                

        BufferedImage imgNew = new BufferedImage(imgOld.getWidth(), imgOld.getHeight(), imgOld.getType());              //create new buffered image                
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) imgNew.getGraphics();                                                               //create new graphics 
        g.rotate(QaDMath.toRadians(deg), imgOld.getWidth()/2, imgOld.getHeight()/2);                                    //configure rotation
        g.drawImage(imgOld, 0, 0, null);                                                                                //draw rotated image
        return imgNew;                                                                                                  //return rotated image                  
    }
```

}

I found many topics related to rotating an image but not a single one discussing the fastest, most  solution.
I hope i didn't miss any topic and this isn't a duplicate.

Hopefully there is someone more skilled than me out there knowing a solution

Comment: Do you need to rotate them at runtime?  Could you instead generate the rotated images you need ahead of time, and then just use the version rotated the proper amount?

Comment: I also thought of this option but fear a few thousand images are too much for the ram used by java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that part of the problem is that you are continually creating new BufferedImages to do the rotation. This results in you doing the painting twice, once when you paint onto the BufferedImage and the second time when you paint the BufferedImage on the frame.

You could try to just paint the existing BufferedImage rotated. For example you could use the [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/) and then just paint the icon using

```
rotated.paintIcon(...);
```

Whenever you need to rotate the image you just use:

```
rotated.setDegrees(...);
```

Simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Rotation3 extends JPanel
{
    private Icon icon;
    private RotatedIcon rotated;
    private int degrees;

    public Rotation3(Image image)
    {
        icon = new ImageIcon( image );
        rotated = new RotatedIcon(icon, 0);
        rotated.setCircularIcon( true );
        setDegrees( 0 );
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(600, 600) );
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        double radians = Math.toRadians( degrees );

        // translate x/y so Icon rotated around a specific point (300, 300)

        int x = 300 - (rotated.getIconWidth() / 2);
        int y = 300 - (rotated.getIconHeight() / 2);
        rotated.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(295, 295, 10, 10);
    }

    public void setDegrees(int degrees)
    {
        this.degrees = degrees;
        rotated.setDegrees(degrees);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    String path = "dukewavered.gif";
                    ClassLoader cl = Rotation3.class.getClassLoader();
                    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(cl.getResourceAsStream(path));
                    final Rotation3 r = new Rotation3(bi);

                    final JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 360, 0);
                    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
                    {
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
                        {
                            int value = slider.getValue();
                            r.setDegrees( value );
                        }
                    });

                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.add(new JScrollPane(r));
                    f.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    f.pack();
                    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Just drag the slider to see the rotation.

Comment: seems like a good idea but my compiler has a problem with the RotatedIcon. Did you write this class too or am I missing a library ?

Comment: @ManuelPrinz I don't really think you need to use the `RotatedIcon`. The performance gain using this approach comes from just painting the image rotated to the screen, rather than creating a rotated version of the image (including memory allocation etc), then drawing the rotated image.

Comment: I'll definitely try that suggestion out but it will take some days to implement it   in the whole game and testing the frame-rate but I will reply again how well it worked. Thank you for your tips.

Comment: @ManuelPrinz, `Did you write this class` - yes, that's why I provided a link to the class.

Comment: `I don't really think you need to use the RotatedIcon.` - correct. The point of the class is to have reusable code with a simple API that you can use anywhere an Icon can be used without recreating the custom painting.

Comment: Due to my stupidity to recognize a link I just wrote the  class myself. After changing the whole painting process it worked perfectly well and improved my frame-rate by round about 700 fps. Additionally it removed problems like dropping fps in specific situations. I think this question is perfectly answered so thank you for your great help - camickr you are a genius =)